# Snake game with a sound system

Tags: c++, game

Is there any way to improve it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include"MMSystem.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

/****************************************************/

/**<Stores Player's Name and Score>*/
struct player
{
    string name;
    int score;
};
/****************************************************/
const int mx1=1,mx2=36,my1=1,my2=20;
int D=3;
int x=(mx2+mx1)/2;
int y=(my2+my1)/2;
bool running=true;
player current;
const int Total_Players=10;
unsigned int z=0;
player high[Total_Players+1];
char MUSIC[100];


/****************************************************/
/**< Function to go to any (x,y) cordinates on console screen */
void gotoxy(int x,int y)
{
    /**< A predefined data type(struct) of windows.h */
    COORD point;
    point.X=x;
    point.Y=y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),point);
}
/***************************************************/
/**< Prints Highscore >**/
void score_print()
{
    system("CLS");
    running=true;
    gotoxy(30,1);
    cout<<"HIGH-SCORES";
    for(int i=0;i<Total_Players;i++)
    {
        gotoxy(20,3+i+i);
        cout<<i+1<<".";
        gotoxy(28,3+i+i);
        cout<<high[i].name;
        gotoxy(52,3+i+i);
        cout<<high[i].score<<endl;
    }
    gotoxy(20,(2*Total_Players)+3);
    cout<<"Press Enter to go to main menu";
    while(running)
    {
        if(getch()==13)
            running=false;
    }

}
/****************************************************/
/**< class of game */
class game
{
    /**< Variables used */
    char FOOD;
    int food;
    int X[100],Y[100],X1[100],Y1[100];
    char BODY[100];
    int XF,YF;
    int flag;
    int temp;
    /****************************************************/
    /**< Function Prints the Map Boundaries */
    void printmap()
    {
        char B;
        B=218;
        gotoxy(mx1,my1);
        cout<<B;
        B=191;
        gotoxy(mx2,my1);
        cout<<B;
        B=217;
        gotoxy(mx2,my2);
        cout<<B;
        B=192;
        gotoxy(mx1,my2);
        cout<<B;
        for(int i=mx1+1;i<my2;i++)
        {
            B=179;
            gotoxy(mx1,i);
            cout<<B;
            gotoxy(mx2,i);
            cout<<B;
        }
        for(int i=my1+1;i<mx2;i++)
        {
             B=196;
             gotoxy(i,my1);
             cout<<B;
             gotoxy(i,my2);
             cout<<B;
        }
        gotoxy(mx2+5,5);
        cout<<"PRESS Q TO QUIT";
        gotoxy(mx2+5,7);
        cout<<"PRESS ENTER TO PAUSE";
    }

    /****************************************************/
    /**< Function to read key press' */
    void keypress(int &x,int &y)
    {
    /**<
         W      UP
        A+D LEFT+RIGHT
         S     DOWN
     */
        int M=getch();
        if(M==224)
            M=getch();
        /**< UP  */
        if((M==72||M==119)&&y!=1)
        {
            y=-1;
            x=0;
        }
        /**< DOWN */
        if((M==80||M==115)&&y!=-1)
        {
            y=1;
            x=0;
        }
        /**< RIGHT */
        if((M==77||M==100)&&x!=-1)
        {
            x=1;
            y=0;
        }
        /**< LEFT */
        if((M==75||M==97)&&x!=1)
        {
            x=-1;
            y=0;
        }
        /**< Q - TO QUIT */
        if(M==113)
        {
            running=false;
        }
        /**< I - FOR INSANE DIFFICULTY */
        if(M==105)
        {
            /**< TOGGLE ON */
            if(flag==0)
            {
                temp=D;
                D=50;
                flag=1;
            }
            /**< TOGGLE OFF */
            else if(flag==1)
            {
                D=temp;
                flag=0;
            }
        }
        /**< ENTER - TO PAUSE */
        if(M==13)
        {
            system("CLS");
            gotoxy(25,5);
            cout<<"PAUSED";
            gotoxy(25,7);
            system("PAUSE");
            system("CLS");
        }
    }
    /****************************************************/
    /**< Function randomises food spawn location, updates score, increases snake length if food is eaten etc */
    void Food(int x,int y)
    {
        /**< if food eaten( Head of snake meets food) */
        if(XF==x&&YF==y)
        {
            F:
            /**< get random coord. */
            XF=rand()%(mx2-1)+(mx1+1);
            YF=rand()%(my2-1)+(my1+1);
            /**< to stop spawn on boundary */
            if(XF==mx1||XF==mx2||YF==my1||YF==my2)
                goto F;
            /**< to stop spawn on snake's body */
            for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
            {
                if(X[i]==XF&&Y[i]==YF)
                    goto F;
            }
            /**< increase score */
            food++;
            /**< add body piece */
            BODY[food-1]='o';
            X[food]=X[food-1];
            Y[food]=Y[food-1]+1;

        }
        /**< print the food */
        gotoxy(XF,YF);
        cout<<FOOD;
        gotoxy(mx2+5,9);
        cout<<"Score: "<<food;
    }
/****************************************************/
/**< Function to update high-score >**/
void update_highscore()
{
    fstream myfile;
    getline(cin,current.name);
    current.score=food;
    while(current.name.length()<z)
    {
        current.name+=" ";
    }
    for(int i=0;i<Total_Players;i++)
    {
        if(current.score>=high[i].score)
        {
            for(int j=Total_Players-1;j>=i;j--)
            {
                high[j+1] = high[j];
            }
            high[i] =  current;
            break;
        }
    }
    myfile.open("bin\\score.txt");
    if(myfile.is_open())
    {
        for(int i=0;i<Total_Players;i++)
        {
            myfile<<" "<<i+1<<","<<high[i].name<<","<<high[i].score<<endl;
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
}

public:
    game()
    {
        FOOD=153;
        food=3;
        XF=YF=10;
        flag=0;
        temp=D;
        /**< initialization of all values for body and its coordinates */
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
            BODY[i]=' ';
            X1[i]=0;
            Y1[i]=-1;
            X[i]=x;
            Y[i]=y+i;
        }
    }
    /*****************************************************/
    /**< moves the snake's body and basically runs the game physics */
    void body_move_print()
    {
        food=3;
        system("CLS");
        if(D==3)
            D=500;
        gotoxy(x,y);
        int i=0;
        int k=0;
        BODY[0]=BODY[1]=BODY[2]='o';
        running=true;
        /**< running snake */
        while(running)
        {
            printmap();
            Sleep(D);
            if(kbhit())
            {
                keypress(X1[0],Y1[0]);
            }
            gotoxy(0,0);
            for(i=0;i<=food;i++)
            {
                X[i]+=X1[i];
                Y[i]+=Y1[i];
                gotoxy(X[i],Y[i]);
                cout<<BODY[i];
            }
            for(i=3;i<food;i++)
            {
                if(X[0]==X[i]&&Y[0]==Y[i])
                {
                    k=10;
                    break;
                }
            }
            for(i=food;i>0;i--)
            {
                X1[i]=X1[i-1];
                Y1[i]=Y1[i-1];
            }
            Food(X[0],Y[0]);
            if(X[0]==mx1||X[0]==mx2||Y[0]==my1||Y[0]==my2||k==10)
            {
                running=false;
                i=600;
                while(i<1100)
                {
                    Beep(i,50);
                    i+=150;
                }
            }
        }
        /**< game over */
        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            if(kbhit())
            {
                if(getch()==13)
                    break;
            }
            Sleep(100);
            system("CLS");
            gotoxy(30,20-i);
            cout<<"GAMEOVER!!";
            gotoxy(30,20-i+1);
            cout<<"SCORE: "<<food;
        }
        system("CLS");
        gotoxy(30,20-i);
        cout<<"GAMEOVER!!";
        gotoxy(30,20-i+1);
        cout<<"SCORE: "<<food;
        gotoxy(30,20-i+2);
        cout<<"NAME:";
        update_highscore();
        gotoxy(30,20-i+3);
        system("PAUSE");
        score_print();
    }
};

/****************************************************/
/**< sets difficulty level */
void diff()
{
    system("CLS");
    int L;
    D=3;
    char D_=221;
    int i=1,j=1;
    for(i=0;i<D;i++)
    {
        gotoxy(33+i,9);
        cout<<D_;
        gotoxy(33,11);
        cout<<"-";
        gotoxy(41,11);
        cout<<"+";
        cout<<"\n\n     LEFT or RIGHT ARROWS to increase or decrease difficulty. Enter to select";
    }
    while(j)
    {

        if(kbhit())
        {
            L=getch();
            if(L==224)
                L=getch();
            if(L==77&&D<=8)
                D++;
            else if(L==75&&D>1)
                D--;
            else if(L==13)
            {
                D=800-D*75;
                break;
            }
            system("CLS");
            for(i=0;i<D;i++)
            {
                gotoxy(33+i,9);
                cout<<D_;
                gotoxy(33,11);
                cout<<"-";
                gotoxy(41,11);
                cout<<"+";
                cout<<"\n\n     LEFT or RIGHT ARROWS to increase or decrease difficulty. Enter to select";
            }
        }
    }

}

/****************************************************/
/**< high score table maker>*/
void score()
{
    fstream myfile;
    string X[Total_Players];
    myfile.open("bin\\score.txt");
    if(myfile.is_open())
    {
        while(!myfile.eof())
        {

            for(int i=0;i<Total_Players;i++)
            {
                getline(myfile,X[i],',');
                getline(myfile,high[i].name,',');
                myfile>>high[i].score;

            }
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    for(int i=0;i<Total_Players;i++)
    {
        if(z<high[i].name.length())
        {
            z=high[i].name.length();
        }
    }
}
/****************************************************/
/**< Sound System >**/
/**< 1. Plays the music >**/
void sound_play()
{
    /**< This line plays the background music on a loop >**/
    PlaySound(MUSIC, NULL, SND_ASYNC|SND_FILENAME|SND_LOOP);
}

/**< Lets you choose the song >**/
void music_select()
{
    int L=0,y=5;
    running=true;
    system("CLS");
    gotoxy(30,3);
    cout<<"/**Song List**/";
    gotoxy(23,5);
    cout<<"1. What does the fox say - Ylvis";
    gotoxy(23,7);
    cout<<"2. Where my baes at - Miranda Sings";
    gotoxy(23,9);
    cout<<"3. Assassin's Creed Unity Theme";
    gotoxy(10,11);
    cout<<"*UP or DOWN to Navigate. ENTER to select. BACKSPACE to go back.*";
    gotoxy(20,y);
    cout<<"->";
    while(running)
    {
        if(kbhit())
        {
            L=getch();
            if(L==224)
                L=getch();
            if(L==72)
            {
                if(y==5)
                    y=9;
                else
                    y=y-2;
            }
            else if(L==80)
            {
                if(y==9)
                    y=5;
                else
                    y=y+2;
            }
            else if(L==13)
            {
                if(y==5)
                {
                    strcpy(MUSIC,"What_Does_The_Fox_Say.wav");
                    sound_play();
                }
                else if(y==7)
                {
                    strcpy(MUSIC,"bin\\Where_My_Baes_At.wav");
                    sound_play();
                }
                else if(y==9)
                {
                       strcpy(MUSIC,"bin\\Assassin's_Creed_Unity_Theme.wav");
                       sound_play();
                }
            }
            else if(L==8)
            {
                running=false;
            }
            system("CLS");
            gotoxy(30,3);
            cout<<"/**Song List**/";
            gotoxy(23,5);
            cout<<"1. What does the fox say - Ylvis";
            gotoxy(23,7);
            cout<<"2. Where my baes at - Miranda Sings";
            gotoxy(23,9);
            cout<<"3. Assassin's Creed Unity Theme";
            gotoxy(10,11);
            cout<<"*UP or DOWN to Navigate. ENTER to select. BACKSPACE to go back.*";
            gotoxy(20,y);
            cout<<"->";
        }

    }
}

/****************************************************/
/**< main menu of game */
void menu()
{
    start:
    int L=0,y=7;
    running=true;
    system("CLS");
    gotoxy(30,5);
    cout<<"/****SNAKE****/";
    gotoxy(30,7);
    cout<<"*Start Game";
    gotoxy(30,9);
    cout<<"*Difficulty";
    gotoxy(30,11);
    cout<<"*Songs";
    gotoxy(30,13);
    cout<<"*High-score";
    gotoxy(30,15);
    cout<<"*Exit";
    gotoxy(15,17);
    cout<<"Press UP or DOWN to navigate and ENTER to select";
    gotoxy(30,19);
    cout<<"/*HELP*/";
    gotoxy(15,21);
    cout<<"*Use ARROW KEYS or W,A,S,D to move the snake.";
    gotoxy(15,22);
    cout<<"*Q to pause.";
    gotoxy(15,23);
    cout<<"*ENTER to exit into menu.";
    gotoxy(27,y);
    cout<<"->";
    while(running)
    {
        if(kbhit())
        {
            L=getch();
            if(L==224)
                L=getch();
            if(L==72)
            {
                if(y==7)
                    y=15;
                else
                    y=y-2;
            }
            else if(L==80)
            {
                if(y==15)
                    y=7;
                else
                    y=y+2;
            }
            else if(L==13)
            {
                if(y==7)
                    running=false;
                else if(y==9)
                {
                    diff();
                    goto start;
                }
                else if(y==11)
                {
                    music_select();
                    goto start;
                }
                else if(y==13)
                {
                    score_print();
                    goto start;
                }
                else if(y==15)
                {
                    system("CLS");
                    exit(0);
                }
            }
            system("CLS");
            gotoxy(30,5);
            cout<<"/****SNAKE****/";
            gotoxy(30,7);
            cout<<"*Start Game";
            gotoxy(30,9);
            cout<<"*Difficulty";
            gotoxy(30,11);
            cout<<"*Songs";
            gotoxy(30,13);
            cout<<"*High-score";
            gotoxy(30,15);
            cout<<"*Exit";
            gotoxy(15,17);
            cout<<"Press UP or DOWN to navigate and ENTER to select";
            gotoxy(30,19);
            cout<<"/*HELP*/";
            gotoxy(15,21);
            cout<<"*Use ARROW KEYS or W,A,S,D to move the snake.";
            gotoxy(15,22);
            cout<<"*Q to pause.";
            gotoxy(15,23);
            cout<<"*ENTER to exit into menu.";
            gotoxy(27,y);
            cout<<"->";
        }
    }
}

/****************************************************/

int main()
{
    /**<Initializing the song for first run >**/
    strcpy(MUSIC,"bin\\What_Does_The_Fox_Say.wav");
    sound_play();

    start:
    score();
    menu();
    srand(time(0));
    game GAME;
    GAME.body_move_print();
    goto start;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, there's (almost) always room for improvement. Is there anything specific you're looking for? Your current statement isn't wrong, but performance/memory/maintainability improvements aren't the same and improving one can make the other worse.

Comment: Thanks for telling me @Mast . Yeah .. I did find a problem in the performance. It lags a little if I'm not running it straight out of the IDE

Comment: I'll update the question as soon as possible

Comment: @DevangJayachandran: As a side not. By placing the code here you are also placing it under the CC license (see the link at the bottom of the page). The cost of us doing a review is that you let everybody use your code.

Comment: I don't mind that.  :P

Comment: @Mast would you un-hold it now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many improvements that could be applied to this code. As it stands, it has several issues or ["code smells"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell):

- **Use of global data**: You are using C++, which supports Object-Oriented programming, and you also already make use of classes in your program, so why declare a bunch of global data when all that could very easily be properly scoped into classes or functions?
- **Very weak names for global variables**: To further aggravate the issue of the globals, some are declared with ludicrous names, such as `x`, `y` and `D`. Those will not only clash with other names you might want to declare, but also convey no meaning or information. The more visible is the scope of a variable, the better and more descriptive its name should be. Loop counter variables are commonly named `i`, `j` and `k` because they have tiny scopes (and for historical reasons, also).
- **Magic numbers**: Your code is swamped with [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)), which makes it very hard to understand and create a mental model of the thing.
- **Using namespace**: Very questionable practice to say the least. Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).
- **Use of `goto`**: In `main()`, where a simple `for(;;)` or `while` would do. That `goto` also threads over the declaration of `GAME`, which is a usage style [full or caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7334968/1198654) and not well known by most programmers. A 'traditional' loop would be much clearer. There are other instances too that seem to exist because you've failed to better divide the code into functions.
- **Lack of spacing makes it very hard to read**: Compare this:

  > ```
  > if(X[0]==mx1||X[0]==mx2||Y[0]==my1||Y[0]==my2||k==10)
  > ```

  To a more spaced equivalent:

  ```
  if (X[0] == mx1 || X[0] == mx2 || Y[0] == my1 || Y[0] == my2 || k == 10)
  ```

---

My opinion, but I think the issues mentioned above makes it hard to review the code in more detail. So my suggestion would be that you first fix those issues and then post a followup question to get more reviews. Bet of luck to you.

Comment: There is no goto above game.. That's making it public

Comment: @DevangJayachandran There is a goto that jumps over the initialization of an instance of the game class inside 'main'. That's what I meant.

Comment: Where exactly do u mean?

Comment: Aah! Works fine in mingw

Comment: @DevangJayachandran, best reference I could find: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7334968

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/92730 - should have added the references from the start, sorry about that.

Comment: Why doesn't it give me an error? Thanks for pointing it out too

Comment: @DevangJayachandran, your usage case is still valid code. The issue is that it is relying on an obscure feature of the language that most people are not familiar with, so a more traditional loop structure, like a `for` or `while` would be a better choice that makes your code clearer.

Comment: Oh! I don't really mind using while. But I find it easier to just put in a goto label and use that instead of putting in multiple loops and conditions for each

Comment: @DevangJayachandran [GOTO is still considered harmful](http://stackoverflow.com/a/52307/1014587). Even when not considering all other points against it, it's not idiomatic C++.